# ¿Cómo cambio el idioma en Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy implementando una tabla paginada con Material, pero tengo el problema de que aparece al pie de la tabla `Items per page:`, refiriéndose a la paginación.

La idea es cambiar ese texto a español ( [ver ejemplos](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) ); intenté cambiando el idioma de mi aplicación en el app.module así:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import es from '@angular/common/locales/es';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
```

pero sin efecto alguno. De igual manera, dentro del html de la implementación de la tabla no aparece una etiqueta con el texto para cambiarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo accediendo a la instancia de paginator así:

```
this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'items por pagina';
```

Answer (score 4):

En nuestro componente importamos:

```
import {MatPaginatorIntl, PageEvent} from "@angular/material/paginator";
```

En el constructor lo llamamos de la siguiente manera y cambiamos por el texto deseado:

```
constructor(
      private paginator: MatPaginatorIntl
  ) {
    this.paginator.itemsPerPageLabel = "Registros por página";
  }
```

Para que tengas una idea más clara puedes imprimir en consola:

```
console.log(this.paginator);
```

Ahí podrás revisar todas las variables a las que puedes acceder y modificar.

Espero te sirva...

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import es from '@angular/common/locales/es';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(es);

@NgModule({
..
providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-PE' } ]
..
})
```

En **app.module.ts** agrega el codigo anterior, ahora si es para Argentina cambia *es-PE* por *es-AR* por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente

```
this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'items por pagina';
```

es la solucion pero en versiones recientes de Angular debe colocarse en el OnInit o onAfterInit

```
async ngOnInit() {    
    console.log(this.resultadosPaginator)
    this.resultadosPaginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel="Registros Por Pagina"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma adecuada en Angular v17.3 es la siguiente:

```js
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginatorIntl, MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SpanishPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  override changes = new Subject<void>();

  override itemsPerPageLabel = 'Items por Página:';
  override nextPageLabel = 'Siguiente página';
  override previousPageLabel = 'Página anterior';

  override getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string => {
    if (length === 0) {
      return `Página 1 de 1`;
    }
    const amountPages = Math.ceil(length / pageSize);
    return `Página ${page + 1} de ${amountPages}`;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'paginator-intl-example',
  templateUrl: 'paginator-intl-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatPaginatorModule],
  providers: [{
    provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
    useClass: SpanishPaginatorIntl,
  }],
})
export class PaginatorIntlExample {}
```

`override` sirve para:

1. Asegurarte de que realmente estás sobrescribiendo un método y no
   creando uno nuevo.
2. Hacer explícito en el código que la intención es sobrescribir un
   método existente.
3. Proporcionar una seguridad adicional durante la compilación al
   verificar contra la clase base.

Este tipo de chequeo estático es muy útil para grandes bases de código y para proyectos con muchos colaboradores, ya que previene una clase común de bugs que ocurren cuando se hacen refactorizaciones. Si el método base cambia y tu método sobrescrito ya no coincide, TypeScript lo marcará como un error, lo que puede ahorrar mucho tiempo de depuración.